# Scrapy FormRequest from response AtrributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Tags: facebook, python-3.x, authentication, scrapy

I am trying to login to Facebook using Scrapy.

I have identified that mobile version of Facebook works without javascript, so I am using it.

The relevant code is

```
from loginform import fill_login_form
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

def parse(self, response):
    """Login to Facebook then pass on"""
    payload = fill_login_form(
        response.request.url,  # https://m.facebook.com
        response.body,
        self.login_user,
        self.login_pass
    )
    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response.request.url,
        formdata=payload,
        formid='login-form',
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

The error I get is:

```
File "/XXX/scraps/scraps/spiders/fb.py", line 44, in parse
    return FormRequest.from_response(response.request.url, formdata=payload, formid='login-form', callback=self.after_login)
  File "/XXX/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 42, in from_response
    kwargs.setdefault('encoding', response.encoding)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Scrapy is on default settings.

I want my spider to login to [m.facebook.com](https://m.facebook.com). I'm pretty sure it is just my weak google-fu, but I was not able to determine, how to move forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `from_response` method requires the first argument to be a `response` object not the url, please check the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects), there's an example that uses the `FormRequest.from_response` to simulate a user login.